# bash --redirect output to log file (with day date in the name)

Tags: linux, bash, logging

I just want to to redirect my script output to a file, to do so I try to redirect the output of a simple command and it works for a particular syntax and not for the other. Could you please have a look and give me any advice, Thanks in advance.
Rgds,
O.

This one is working fine:

```
du -h > "/var/log/mytst.$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M).log"
```

and this doesn't:

```
du -h > /var/log/mytst."$(date +"%D--%H:%M:%S")".log 2>&1
```

Any idea?

Comment: What about the second command doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Look at this output:

```
$ echo "/var/log/mytst.$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M).log"
/var/log/mytst.2014-08-11_13:54.log
$ echo /var/log/mytst."$(date +"%D--%H:%M:%S")".log
/var/log/mytst.08/11/14--13:54:00.log
```

The second one expects a tree hierarchy to exist, as the `/`'s in the output of `date +%D` are treated as directory separators. Your question does not state *how* the second version 'does not work', so I would bet the error is `No such file or directory`.

Comment: Thanks, now it makes sense but yesterday I was a bit confused; I will now format the date with "-" to avoid this error msg.